# Replace a value in a query using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query at postgresql:

```
COPY (SELECT 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."ID_UR", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."IDEDOMUN15", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX1", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX2", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX3", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX4", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX5", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX6", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX7", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX8", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX9", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX10", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX11", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX12", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX13", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX14", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX15", 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."PIX16" 
FROM 
public."UR_16PIX_Chih"
WHERE 
"UR_16PIX_Chih"."IDEDOMUN15" = '08061') TO 
'/home/manager/data/Chihuahua/08061.csv' WITH CSV HEADER;
```

I want to know How I could replace the value '08061' with '08062', next with '08063', next with '08064', next with '08065' and so... using an automatic way. Meanwhile I'm just editing the query replacing the '08061' value with next values in pgadmin sql editor but I need a way for doing so automatically.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do could be done in MS Excel easily. Break your whole query in 5 parts, so both `08061` are the only values in 2nd and 4th columns. Then drag `08061` and fill series, so it will generate number. At last concatenate all 5 columns again to generate your queries.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Utsav. I don't want to replace the value into table, I want to do that in query only.

Answer (score 0):

One option is a `PL/pgSQL` function:

```
create or replace function c()
returns void as $c$
declare r record;
begin
    for r in
        select distinct "IDEDOMUN15" as i
        from public."UR_16PIX_Chih"
    loop
    execute format($$
        copy (
            select "ID_UR", ...
            from public."UR_16PIX_Chih"
            where "IDEDOMUN15" = '%1$s'
        ) to '/var/lib/pgsql/%1$s.csv'
    $$, r.i);
    end loop;
end;
$c$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Great!, That's just that I was finding out. Thanks, Cloaldo. I will try it

Comment: I tried so yet but query returned with no results. What's wrong?

Comment: @Without data to test it is impossible to know.